# Не создаётся архив в PHP

Tags: php, ziparchive

Пытаюсь создать Zip-архив. Выдаёт такие ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что в php.ini нужно изменить какие-то настройки, но какие?

Comment: Надпись `No such file or directory` не наводит на мысли?

Comment: Теперь вылезает ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "ZipArchive" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\landing-constructor-2023\index_old.php on line 16
( ! ) Error: Class "ZipArchive" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\landing-constructor-2023\index_old.php on line 16

Comment: `Class "ZipArchive" not found` <-- здесь описана суть ошибки. Вы какого ответа ожидаете?

Comment: Да это я понимаю. Класс ZipArchive должен быть встроенным. Это не класс, который я сам создаю. Оно должно быть прописано в php.ini

Comment: А `phpinfo()` что показывает?

Comment: А какая именно информация phpinfo() нужна?

Comment: Ну так по ошибке можно было погуглить. [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Comment: попробуй перед ZipArchive поставить \ чтоб было **\ZipArchive**